# No search results appear after first pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter and seeking some help here.

I am making a test app with pagination. It works fine until the first result but when clicked on 'Next' or 'Any Pagination' tells no results were found.

I think it calls for url alright but don't know what else is the problem.

http://localhost/admin/search/search-results/2

My controller:

```
public function pagination(){
$keyword = $this->input->post('search[1]');
$main_keyword = $this->search_model->get_city_id_by_input($keyword);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'search/search-results/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->search_model->total_number_of_rows($main_keyword);
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = $this->search_model->total_number_of_rows($main_keyword);
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_search_results($main_keyword, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
function get_city_id_by_input($keyword){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('vbc_city');
    $this->db->where('v_city_name', $keyword);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->result_array();
    return $query_result();
}
  public function total_number_of_rows($main_keyword) {
      $this->db->select('vbc_item_id');
      $this->db->from('vbc_vacation_item_attri');
      $this->db->where('v_item_city', $main_keyword);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->num_rows();
}
  public function get_search_results($main_keyword, $perpage, $offset) {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('vbc_vacation_item_attri');
      $this->db->where('v_item_city', $main_keyword);
      $this->db->limit($perpage, $offset);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result;
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact you're getting data with POST. Post information gets lost after the second page. If you use get to navigate trough the pagination, you will get it to work

Comment: Thanks @PhiterFernandes.. Is it something to do with search form? I have this code `<?php echo form_open('search/search-results'); ?>` on the form opening.Do I have to use `method="get"` here?

Comment: Yes if you use method GET and in the php file instead of `$keyword = $this->input->post('search[1]');` you use `$keyword = $this->input->get('search[1]');`, it should work.

Comment: Thanks again @PhiterFernandes.. It didn't work but at least I got an idea which direction to go..

Comment: Well you probably will need to change a few things also but that's kind of the way to do it. Glad to help ;D